# How to audit and show which user made changes to a GKE node pool using Logs Explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to determine the user/serviceaccount that made changes to a node pool within my GKE cluster.

### For example:

Openning Log Explorer: `logName: "projects/spotinst-labs/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"`

There is a method called: `google.container.v1.ClusterManager.SetNodePoolSize`

However, in the returned log there is no `authenticationInfo`, normally its returned in `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail`.

Does anyone know how I would be able to retrieve who made changes on the given node pool?

Answer (score 2):

Every Node pool in a GKE Cluster has a corresponding “Managed Instance Group” GCE resource created; we can view MIG details in Node pool details under the “Instance groups” section.

When I make any modification in the Node pool size there are logs created for the corresponding MIG. These logs have field,`methodName: "v1.compute.instanceGroups.addInstances"`(if the Node pool size is increased)  or `methodName: "v1.compute.instanceGroups.removeInstances"` (if Node pool size is decreased) and also `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail` with Default GCE Service Account in my case.

So, with the help of MIG logs of corresponding Node pools we can retrieve the Identity of the User/Service Account that made changes to a given Node pool.

**Update:**

To view the User that made change to the Node pool size use the following log query,

```
 logName="projects/[PROJECT-ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"  
 protoPayload.methodName="google.container.v1.ClusterManager.SetNodePoolSize
```

Comment: As you mentioned these methods all show the default google API Service Agent in the principalEmail. I am looking for the actual IAM user that resized the node pool. Any ideas on how to find that?

Comment: Yes we can using the following log query:  _logName="projects/[ROJECT-ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" protoPayload.methodName="google.container.v1.ClusterManager.SetNodePoolSize"_ 
 Let me know if this log query answers your question, So I can update the solution if required?